# IntelliJ IDEA показывает "характер"

Tags: intellij-idea, sdk, java

Как-то пришлось перезагрузить зависший комп. В итоге IntelliJ самостоятельно поменяла тему оформления и начала сыпать ошибками. Переустановил JDK (правда, была 1.7, сейчас 18), IDE (и 2016 пробовал, и 2017). Открываю: вроде работает, но иконки неактивны и не добавляются классы/интерфейсы.

Что это может быть и как пофиксить? Могла ли повлиять версия JDK, и если да, то где теперь откопать 1.7? При этом NetBeans работает, как ни в чем не бывало.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настроил. Если кто-то столкнется с подобной проблемой - вот решение:

- во-первых (хотя это и так понятно), установите нужную версию в "File -> Project Structure -> Project Settings";
- во-вторых, проверьте, чтобы в "File -> Settings -> Compiler -> Java Compiler -> Target bytecode version" также все было правильно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ответ надо писать в ответы, а не в вопрос.

Answer (score 5):

Скорей всего проблема в "испорченных" локальных настройках. Удалите или восстановите эти настройки из резервной копии.

Настройки хранятся:

- Windows Vista, 7, 8, 10 - `<SYSTEM DRIVE>\Users\<USER ACCOUNT NAME>\.<PRODUCT><VERSION>`
- Windows XP - `<SYSTEM DRIVE>\Documents and Settings\<USER ACCOUNT NAME>\.<PRODUCT><VERSION>`
- Linux - `~/.<PRODUCT><VERSION>`
- MacOS - `~/Library/Preferences/<PRODUCT><VERSION>`

Более подробно можно прочесть в [документации](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-intellij-idea-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html).

Comment: Папка с локальными настройками удаляется при деинсталляции. Я уже раза 3-4 переустанавливал. Боюсь, что придется сносить ОС, хотя если в будущем такое повторится, каждый раз сносить - не вариант вообще.

Comment: вы проверили, что она удаляется?

Comment: Разумеется. Думается мне, что дело все-таки в версии JDK. Например, в NetBeans тоже выскакивала ошибка, пока не поковырялся в настройках. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JUgmoqSnk6M Где это изменять в IntelliJ, право, не знаю. По документации лез в Свойства компьютера > Доп. параметры системы > Переменные среды и ковырялся там: результата 0.